# How to find eigenvector of inverse of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrices A and B are invertible and have the same eigenvector **v** for different corresponding eigenvalues. Show that the inverse of (AB) also has eigenvector **v** and find the corresponding eigenvalue.

I'm stuck on this problem and would really appreciate some help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. So, let's say $Av = \lambda v$, $Bv = \mu v$. Now compute 
$$ (AB)v = A(Bv) = A(\mu v) = \mu Av = \ldots $$
and multiply both sides by $(AB)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you, I got it!

Answer (score 0):

let $B(\vec{v}) = b\vec{v}
B^{-1}B(\vec{v}) = \vec{v} = B^{-1}(b\vec{v})\implies \frac{1}{b}$ is eigenvalue for eigenvector $\vec{v}$ for $B^{-1}$
similarly $\frac{1}{a}$ is eigenvalue for eigenvector $\vec{v}$ for $A^{-1}$

now $B^{-1}A^{-1}\vec{v} = \frac{1}{a} B^{-1}\vec{v} = \frac{1}{ab}\vec{v}$